# migrating keras + tensorflow cpu to tensorflow-gpu keras modelling

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I'm a beginner of data-science and by now, I'm trying to migrate old code keras cpu modelling to gpu-tensorflow.

fyi: I'm following instruction on prof.jeffheaton videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrkEYf-YDyI | [2020, TensorFlow 2.0 GPU (CUDA), Keras, & Python 3.7 in Windows 10]
and install environment as noticed here:
https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/tensorflow-gpu.yml

and from nvidia, i had installed:
ms.visual code 2019

- cuda_11.5.1_496.13_windows -- include driver.exe
- cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.3.1.22_cuda11.5-archive.zip

and as result on phyton:
`import tensorflow as tf`
i got result: 
2021-12-04 18:02:41.467262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

and for:
`tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

it result: 
2021-12-04 18:02:41.467262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.986777: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.993GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 13.41GiB/s
2021-12-04 18:04:50.986857: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.986900: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.986939: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.986978: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.987016: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.987054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.987093: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-12-04 18:04:50.987155: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

---

and here the cpu modeling code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

```
###CPU Build from
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv1D ,MaxPooling1D, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError as rmse
from keras import optimizers
```

and it still run normal for cpu code line:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',padding = 'same',input_shape=(120,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= 'mse' , metrics = [rmse()])
```

#### migrate to tensorflow gpu keras

```
from tensorflow import keras ##GPU
from tensorflow.keras import layers ##GPU
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential ##GPU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

```
import math
# from tensorflow import keras ##GPU
# from tensorflow.keras import layers ##GPU
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv1D ,MaxPooling1D, Dropout,LSTM
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError as rmse
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
```

```
# define model for GPU
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',padding = 'same',input_shape=(120,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True)) ##bermasalah
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = False)) ##bermasalah
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  ##aselinya
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(16,))) ##versipanjang

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss= 'mse' , metrics = [rmse()])
```

and as far as i know.,
this line is make me stucked:
`model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = True))`

and
`model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences = False))`

i've also already try to read lstm on tensorflow..
somebody please help me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-12-04 18:02:41.467262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
```

The above mentioned codes starts from `I` are just `(I)`information messages and are not errors.

you can surpass `(I)`informational messages and `(W)`warnings by using the code below:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

I also replicated the above mentioned code in both `CPU` and `GPU` runtime mode in `Google colab` using `TF 2.7, 2.8`, which does not show any error.